# Twin Axes overrides original Axes' ticks

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am facing a surprising behaviour regarding tick locators and twin axes.
I have an `Axes` object, and set a `matplotlib.dates.DayLocator` as its major locator, and a `matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter` as its major formatter.

```
import datetime as dt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import figure as mpfig
from matplotlib.backends import backend_agg as mpback
from matplotlib import dates as mpdates

start = dt.datetime(2018, 2, 16)
end = start + dt.timedelta(days=10)

fig = mpfig.Figure(figsize=(16, 4))
mpback.FigureCanvas(fig)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mpdates.DayLocator())
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mpdates.DateFormatter("%d/%m %H:%M"))

ax.grid(True)

x = np.arange(start, end, dt.timedelta(days=1)).astype(dt.datetime)
y = np.random.randint(10, 1000, size=x.size)
ax.plot(x, y)

fig.savefig('test.png')
```

[image]

Then, I create a twin `Axes` of it, with `ax.twinx()`
But as soon as I plot something on the new `Axes`, the tick format becomes the default one.

```
# ...
x = np.arange(start, end, dt.timedelta(days=1)).astype(dt.datetime)
y = np.random.randint(10, 1000, size=x.size)
ax2 = ax.twinx()
ax2.plot(x, y)
```

[image]
As you can see, the format is not the `"%d/%m %H:%M"` I specified anymore, but has become `"%y-%m-%d"`.

Even more disturbing, if I set the x window and then plot something on `ax2`, my tick locator is ignored, and a default one is used.

```
# ...
ax.set_xlim(start, start + dt.timedelta(days=1))
ax.plot(x, y)
```

This code yield this figure:

[image]

```
# ...
ax.set_xlim(start, start + dt.timedelta(days=1))

ax2 = ax.twinx()
ax2.plot(x, y)
```

But this creates that:

[image]
Major ticks appeared at (I assume) default locations.

According to , the new `Axes` and the original one should share their limits, ticks and scale on the X axis:

*Doc about [`Figure.add_axes`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.figure.Figure.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.add_axes), called by `Axes.twinx`*

> sharex, sharey : Axes, optional
>
> Share the x or y axis with sharex and/or sharey. The axis will have the same limits, ticks, and scale as the axis of the shared axes.

So, what am I missing here?
Why does plotting on `ax2` has any impact on `ax`'s ticks, which I manually set?

Comment: I guess you will want to first create the twin axes and then set the locator/formatter.

Comment: The problem will only appear with dates or other unitized data. In principle one could add a check if the axis already has the correct units set when something is plotted to a twin axes. If you feel strongly about it, you can open [an issue](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues).